# How Do I Add Text Over Column Images

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am currently trying to add text over images, which is relatively simple, however, I hit a snag. I am trying to add text over images that I set to a column, and all the text is forcing itself on the last image (the column is 3 column by 1 row).

Help?

Here is the code I am working with:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./bin/images/lecture.jpg" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./bin/images/identify.jpg" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="./bin/images/roadmap.jpg" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @David, can you please provide code example with text in it or a screenshot regarding how it looks currently. That will help me to understand your question correctly.

Comment: I did add the code above

Answer (score 1):

Using css properties `position: relative` and `position: absolute` could be answer to your problem. Try this code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="overlay">
    sample text 1
    </div>
    <img src="./bin/images/lecture.jpg" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="overlay">
    sample text 2
    </div>
    <img src="./bin/images/identify.jpg" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="overlay">
    sample text 3
    </div>
    <img src="./bin/images/roadmap.jpg" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.column .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: could you share your full code and screenshot, because this should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to extend and convert @Aryan Twanju's answer in working example. Please review it by running below given code and let us know if you are looking for it or something different.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.column .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="overlay">
      Sample Text 1
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="overlay">
      Sample Text 2
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="overlay">
      Sample Text 3
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="sampletext" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, (i dont know about firefox or edge) open developer tools. use the select element tool. click on your text. it should show you how large the element or div it is in actually is. if it is small, use css to make the div it is in, or the p element itself larger.